# How to make bot respond to a certain msg?

Tags: discord.py

So, I've been trying to make my bot respond to a specific keyword however when I do this the bot either doesn't respond or gives me a bunch of errors. I've tried a few methods of doing this but I didn't have much luck. If anybody can make it work would be glad here are one of the methods I tried using.

```
    if message.content == "keyword":
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Response {0.author.mention}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways, either with the commands extension, or within the `on_message` event.

Below is an example of how you can do this. With this example, when a user types "!ping" the bot will respond with "Pong". If a message contains the word "foo", then the bot will respond with "bar".

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('client ready')

@client.command()
async def ping():
    await client.say('Pong')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.id != message.author.id:
        if 'foo' in message.content:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, 'bar')

    await client.process_commands(message)

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: This is great! However when i used this example the bot responds to itself. For example i did

`@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'test' in message.content:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'testing')`




The bot responds to itself, Repeating one after another creating a spam texts is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The `on_message` event triggers for every message, including ones sent from the bot. You'll have to include a check where the code does not execute if it's a message from the bot. I've updated my code with an example.

Comment: I'm really sorry for asking too many questions :P but i'm really new to coding so please bare with me here, I tried your example and replaced the message.author.id with my bot's id, however i'm a bit stuck. I did await client.delete_message(message) so it deletes it. But it does the same thing all over again, My question is, What should i make my bot do after?

Comment: You don't need to replace anything for the above to work. `client.user.id` is already your bot ID. The code then checks it against `message.author.id`, which is the ID of the user that sent the message. If the two are not equal (using `!=`), it means that the bot did not send the message so it can continue to the rest of the code