# Create an async function for my discord bot that can be run at any time

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot using Discord's discord.py API.

I've seen that by creating `on_message()` and `on_ready()` functions, I can make my bot do things when a message is sent, or when the bot is started, but if I want my bot to do something without needing to restart my bot or sending a message, what should I do?

I need to do that because I'm creating an API for my bot, so if I write `say(channel, "Hello")`, that should make my bot, without restarting it or sending any message to the bot, say Hello on the channel Id specified.

Comment: Is this meant to be automatic? What kind of intervals would this run at (regular, irregular)?

Comment: Are you asking how to send a message from some other coroutine you're writing?(use `await bot.send_message(channel, "hello")`) Or are you asking how to trigger the bot to send a message?  You'll have to define a listener that is listening for some event. What would trigger your bot to send this message?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I am trying to trigger my bot to say something, like a simple `await client.send_message()`, but it needs to run or when the bot is started (`on_ready`) or when a message is sent (`on_message()`), but I want my bot to say a message if someone using my API, writes `say(40858945805, "Hello")`, without restarting it or sending any message to the bot.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh because the function needs to be awaited if I want my bot to do something, it needs to be inside `on_start()` or `on_message`, but there's no function `whenever()`, so if I want my bot to do something, it can only be or when the bot is started, or when a message is sent, but if I want my bot to do something when I want, what should I do?

Comment: First link has example of creating a background task, while second has example of creating commands. Do either of these fit your use case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835742/how-to-send-a-message-with-discord-py-without-a-command https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50216043/how-to-make-bot-respond-to-a-certain-msg

Comment: When you say "API", do you mean a REST API (or other web interface), where you're sending requests to your bot over a network?  Or do you mean that you want to start your bot in an interactive mode and call coroutines from your terminal?